# Apache Camel: Exhausted after delivery attempt -> how debug?

Tags: apache-camel

Currently, I am using Camel as an orchestration engine (it receives a HTTP POST request which results into the Camel code sending HTTP POST/PUT/GET requests to some external servers, until at the end Camel sends (hopefully) a 200 OK back to the initiator of the 1st HTTP POST request).

load tool <-> Camel code <-> external server(s)

I am using Camel 2.9.2.

In order to check the performance, I am using httperf to send a lot of HTTP POST messages to our Camel implementation. When httperf is configured to send requests at a rate of 100 requests per second, I see the following error a lot:

> ERROR Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-wpm-seal-59304-133965736935
>   6-0-3482128 on ExchangeId: ID-wpm-seal-59304-1339657369356-0-3482126).
>   Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: org.apache.camel.
>   component.http.HttpOperationFailedException: HTTP operation failed
>   invoking http://anExternalServer.com:7000/M2M/resources/m2mSubscription
>   ?subscriptionId=32477000000 with statusCode: 500

I wonder how to debug to see what is causing this error ...

And also what it means:
 1) does it mean that Camel could not further handle the request ? 
 2) does it mean that Camel tried to send a HTTP message to an external server, but this server did not reply/accept the request (maybe it could not accept the request due to overload) ?
  -> this looked the most logical to me, but a wireshark trace showed that Camel did not try to setup a TCP connection to that external server ... ?!
 3) or ...

Maybe I hit a limitation of number of TCP connections ? Or threads ?

Here is the full error dump:

> DefaultErrorHandler            ERROR Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-wpm-seal-59304-133965736935
>   6-0-3482128 on ExchangeId: ID-wpm-seal-59304-1339657369356-0-3482126). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: org.apache.camel.
>   component.http.HttpOperationFailedException: HTTP operation failed invoking http://anExternalServer.com:7000/M2M/resources/m2mSubscription
>   ?subscriptionId=32477000000 with statusCode: 500
>   org.apache.camel.component.http.HttpOperationFailedException: HTTP operation failed invoking http://anExternalServer.com:7000/M2M/resource
>   s/m2mSubscription?subscriptionId=32477000000 with statusCode: 500
>           at org.apache.camel.component.http.HttpProducer.populateHttpOperationFailedException(HttpProducer.java:229)[camel-http-2.9.2
>   .jar:2.9.2]
>           at org.apache.camel.component.http.HttpProducer.process(HttpProducer.java:157)[camel-http-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
>           at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper
>   .java:61)[camel-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
>           at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[camel-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
>           at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor$2.doInAsyncProducer(SendProcessor.java:115)[camel-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
>           at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doInAsyncProducer(ProducerCache.java:285)[camel-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
>           at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:110)[camel-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
>           at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[camel-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
>           at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99)[camel-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
>           at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)[camel-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
>           at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:71)[camel-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2
>   ]
>           at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[camel-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
>           at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99)[camel-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
>           at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)[camel-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
>           at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.TraceInterceptor.process(TraceInterceptor.java:91)[camel-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
>           at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[camel-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
>           at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.processErrorHandler(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:333)[camel-core-2.9.2.j
>   ar:2.9.2]
>           at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:223)[camel-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
>           at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.StreamCachingInterceptor.process(StreamCachingInterceptor.java:52)[camel-core-2.9.
>   2.jar:2.9.2]
>           at org.apache.camel.processor.RouteContextProcessor.processNext(RouteContextProcessor.java:45)[camel-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
>           at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)[camel-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
>           at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.DefaultChannel.process(DefaultChannel.java:304)[camel-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
>           at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[camel-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
>           at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:117)[camel-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
>           at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80)[camel-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
>           at org.apache.camel.processor.RouteContextProcessor.processNext(RouteContextProcessor.java:45)[camel-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
>           at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)[camel-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
>           at org.apache.camel.processor.UnitOfWorkProcessor.process(UnitOfWorkProcessor.java:122)[camel-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
>           at org.apache.camel.processor.RouteInflightRepositoryProcessor.processNext(RouteInflightRepositoryProcessor.java:50)[camel-c
>   ore-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
>           at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)[camel-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
>           at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[camel-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
>           at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99)[camel-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
>           at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)[camel-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
>           at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:71)[camel-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2
>   ]
>           at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[camel-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
>           at org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectProducer.process(DirectProducer.java:61)[camel-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
>           at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[camel-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
>           at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor$2.doInAsyncProducer(SendProcessor.java:115)[camel-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
>           at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doInAsyncProducer(ProducerCache.java:285)[camel-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
>           at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:110)[camel-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
>           at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[camel-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
>           at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99)[camel-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
>           at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)[camel-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
>           at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:71)[camel-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2
>   ]
>           at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[camel-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
>           at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99)[camel-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
>           at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)[camel-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
>           at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.TraceInterceptor.process(TraceInterceptor.java:91)[camel-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
>           at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[camel-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
>           at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.processErrorHandler(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:333)[camel-core-2.9.2.j
>   ar:2.9.2]
>           at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:223)[camel-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
>           at org.apache.camel.processor.RouteContextProcessor.processNext(RouteContextProcessor.java:45)[camel-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
>           at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)[camel-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
>           at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.DefaultChannel.process(DefaultChannel.java:304)[camel-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
>           at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[camel-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
>           at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:117)[camel-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
>           at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80)[camel-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
>           at org.apache.camel.processor.RouteContextProcessor.processNext(RouteContextProcessor.java:45)[camel-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
>           at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)[camel-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
>           at org.apache.camel.processor.UnitOfWorkProcessor.processAsync(UnitOfWorkProcessor.java:150)[camel-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
>           at org.apache.camel.processor.UnitOfWorkProcessor.process(UnitOfWorkProcessor.java:117)[camel-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
>           at org.apache.camel.processor.RouteInflightRepositoryProcessor.processNext(RouteInflightRepositoryProcessor.java:50)[camel-c
>   ore-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
>           at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)[camel-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
>           at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[camel-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
>           at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99)[camel-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
>           at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)[camel-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
>           at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:71)[camel-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2
>   ]
>           at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:99)[camel-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
>           at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:86)[camel-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
>           at org.apache.camel.component.http.CamelServlet.service(CamelServlet.java:94)[camel-http-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)[servlet-api.jar:]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)[catalina.jar:7.0.25]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)[catalina.jar:7.0.25]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)[catalina.jar:7.0.25]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)[catalina.jar:7.0.25]
>           at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)[catalina.jar:7.0.25]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)[catalina.jar:7.0.25]
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)[catalina.jar:7.0.25]
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)[catalina.jar:7.0.25]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)[catalina.jar:7.0.25]
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)[catalina.jar:7.0.25]
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)[tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.25]
>           at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)[tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.25]
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)[tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.25]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)[:1.6.0_22]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)[:1.6.0_22]
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)[:1.6.0_22]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look on the http server side, as HTTP error code 500 is a failure on the server, not in the client side where you use Camel.

Comment: Thanks Claus. You are correct. It would be nice if some more info could be printed as to why the server side can not accept the HTTP request. Can I somehow retrieve this info ? (or only via a wireshark trace, but this is hard to diagnose during periods of high load)

Comment: That depends on what the server sends back in the http body. The HttpOperationFailedException exception has methods to access the http body, so in case there was more details, you can access that and log it. Also many of the http components has logging you can enable to see what data is send over the network.